# How do I pass a TensorFlow Dataset through a TensorFlow Transform pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-transform

I have implemented a [custom TensorFlow Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset) for my raw data. I can download, prepare, and load the data as a `tensorflow.data.Dataset` as follows:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets

builder = tensorflow_datasets.builder("my_dataset")
builder.download_and_prepare()
ds = builder.as_dataset()
```

I want to transform this data in a [TensorFlow Transform pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started) for model training. However, the only way I have been able to pass the dataset in to the transform pipeline is by converting it to instance dicts and passing in raw data metadata.

```py
instance_dicts = tensorflow_datasets.as_dataframe(ds).to_dict(orient="records")
with tensorflow_transform.beam.Context():
    (transformed_data, _), transform_fn = (
        instance_dicts,
        RAW_DATA_METADATA,
    ) | tensorflow_transform.beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(
        preprocessing_fn, output_record_batches=True
    )
```

Is there an easier and more memory efficient way of passing a TensorFlow Dataset to a TensorFlow Transform pipeline?

Comment: Could you please have a look at this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census#transform_the_data). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the easier and more memory efficient way to pass a Tensorflow Dataset to a Tensorflow Transform pipeline is to reference the TFRecord files written by the Tensorflow Dataset Builder's `download_and_prepare()` job.

```py
import apache_beam
from apache_beam.io import tfrecordio

examples_dir = tensorflow_datasets.builder("my_dataset").info.data_dir
examples_file_pattern = f"{examples_dir}/my_dataset-*"

with apache_beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    with tensorflow_transform.beam.Context():
        raw = pipeline | tfrecordio.ReadFromTFRecord(file_pattern=examples_file_pattern)
```

To transform the raw data, create a TFXIO from a feature spec.

```
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata.schema_utils import schema_from_feature_spec
from tfxio.public import tfxio

example_spec = {
    "token": tensorflow.io.FixedLenFeature([], tensorflow.string),
    "label": tensorflow.io.FixedLenFeature([], tensorflow.string),
}
schema = schema_from_feature_spec(example_spec)
tfexample_tfxio = tfxio.TFExampleBeamRecord(physical_format=["tfrecord"], schema=schema)
```

Then in the pipeline, convert the `PCollection` to a Beam source, and provide the appropriate adapter to convert `RecordBatch` to Tensors.

```
        # ...
        (transformed_data, _), transform_fn = (
            (raw | tfexample_tfxio.BeamSource()),
            tfexample_tfxio.TensorAdapterConfig(),
        ) | tensorflow_transform.beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(
            preprocessing_fn, output_record_batches=True
        )
```